# How can I query the insights against a Facebook custom action story object?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I have created a Facebook App and a custom object and action to use in a custom story. So far so good. This allows a user to post a custom story saying

> [User] is [doing some action to] a [some object]

I want to query insights as follows:-

- Show me insights on the stories that have been posted about a specific object
- Show me insights on a specific story

For this example:

> Dave is watching The Walking Dead Season 4 Episode 1

I want to be able to

- Query a summary of insights on all of the stories about The Walking Dead Season 4 Episode 1
- Drill into the results and query the insights on only Dave's post about The Walking Dead Season 4 Episode 1

I know that you can get summary data but that's not what I need. Also, I know that if you request the right permission from the person posting the story you can query their insights but again that's not what I'm looking for (and I can't imagine that any user is going to let me have access to all of their insights anyway).

Has anybody got any ideas please?

Comment: I don't believe there is such an API - have you seen an example or doc suggesting there is?

Comment: No but as a developer, if I were designing Insights I would expect other developers to want to use it that way so I was hoping they might have built the functionality in..